# solve this error: "The type or name 'Collections' does not existe in the namespace 'System'. (Are you missing an assembly or a reference)"?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

This is the thing: System.Collections should be available for most of .NET Frameworks, that is, including .NET Standard 2.0, Core, and others.

The code that is failing is `using System.Collections;`

I have a solution in VS 2019, with 5 projects:

2 of them are for Xamarin.Forms and the Android that goes with it, aiming to tackle Android Pie 9.0
1 of them is a library for Xamarin, same conditions than the previous 2. This is where we can find the error.
2 of them are libraries in .NET Standard 2.0.

I have done a little bit of research and the solution was to target the same framework in all of the projects, however this is not possible as I don't find the target framework for the Xamarin projects (the full 3 of them), and according to MS website the namespace should be available.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Update: I have tried dotnet restore, but it is not recognized, after further looking, this command is for .NET core, not for standandard

Comment: Did you create a class in a folder or a namespace called Collections?

Comment: one possibility here is that the entire TFM is missing; have you done `dotnet restore` at the command line? did it work?

Comment: no, some projects were created by myself, other ones by colleagues. I don't get why this is not working for me but to another colleagues

Comment: dotnet restore? never heard of it, I will try, thanks

Comment: >dotnet restore
Command "dotnet" is not valid.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an .NetStandard20 project referencing a .NetStandard21 project. Upward framework references can cause funny errors like that. I now check that first.

Comment: Yes, I have checked that many times, 2 projects in .NET Standard 2.0, and the rest are for Xamarin

Comment: @lria Can you provide some code that having this error message?

Comment: the code is in the using statement, I've already added at the begining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did sort it.

dotnet can not be run on VS because it is Standard and not Core, as I said. But I was able to run it from command line.

Then it was not working fully, so I tried to change the target framework in the project that was erroring, put it to 2.1 instead of 2.0, that kind of work. Some of the errors were still there, but this one in particular was gone. My guess is that the library included some nuget packages that needed 2.1, because the libraries that we built, all of them target 2.0.

Then there was some change in the library done by the colleague of mine that was in charge of that part that solved everything. So I guess it was a nuget package the whole problem.

Answer (score -1):

Install Do select `Dotnet Desktop Development` from Visual studio installer

If it wont work for time being right click on project --> Manage Nuget Packages --> Install `Systems.Collections`

Last resort: looks like your Visual Studio is corrupted. Completely uninstall and reinstall.